# How to identify UNUserNotificationCenter is came(:didReceive)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

Here I use UNUserNotificationCenter to trigger notifications repeatedly. I had a problem when the notification was triggered I wanted to call the function without action. can someone tell me how to do that?

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print(" Foreground Notification IS CALLED ")
        completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(" Nikan Did recieve calling ")

        if response.actionIdentifier == "Okay" {
            print(" Notification Clickced ")
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    func createNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Notification"
        content.subtitle = "Wow, Notification"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "Actions"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.defaultRingtone

        // show this notification five seconds from now
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
        // choose a random identifier
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // notification actions
        let okay = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Okay", title: "Okay", options: .destructive)
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Actions", actions: [okay], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

        //    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                // Something went wrong
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
```

I want an answer to call a function when UNUserNotificationCenter's notification is triggered.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. didReceive not called? 
didReceive called after delivery notice. For it to be invoked, it is necessary to UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

Comment: Hi @neskafesha. Here I ask, How to call a function when a notification is received?

Comment: Function willPresent called before present notification, you can use it

Comment: I think it's only for Foreground. I want to know if there is any function for Suspend state without any action.

Comment: application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
It's working only for push notification (with APNS, NO UNUserNotification). This function working in backgroundMode.

Answer (score 0):

Question: How to call a function when a notification is received?

Answer:
When you receive notification (:didReceive), post NSNotification and observe it in your UIViewController.
Call the function in observer's #selecteor method.

DidReceive triggers when tap on push notification, in your case app is is in background and if the app is opening by clicking on push notification, then DidReveive will be triggered.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let pushInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
// post NSNotification here
// You also have data fetched from push notification (if any) in pushInfo variable
}
```

Comment: Yes, is it can observe in the kill(Suspend) state?

Comment: @ThushalMadhushanka I updated an answer in detail, please check.

Comment: Won't observe if killed, but can be observed as soon as app opens through push notification.

Comment: ah Thank you Izaan , I want to do it in the killing state. Do you know any other way to identify these notifications, or Do you know any other method to run the timer in the kill/suspend state?

Comment: I don't think there an option to run function when app is terminated/killed.